# How to add values in BiMap JAVA 8?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, bimap

I am trying to create a BiMap.

```
BiMap<Integer, Map<Item, Boolean>> rankedItem = HashBiMap.create();

            for (Catalogue catlogue : latestItemCataloug) {

                String name = catlogue.getName();

                List<Item> itemList = map.get(name);

                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(itemList)) {
                    itemList.stream().limit(max)
                            .peek(c -> c.setPrice(getPrice()))
                            .forEach(e -> {
                                Map<Item, Boolean> itemMap =
                                        new HashMap<>();
                                itemMap.put(e, true)
                                rankedItem.put(
                                        itemList.indexOf(e),
                                       );
                            });
                }
            }
```

It works fine but Is there a better way to do this? I am trying to improve my coding. Please suggests how can I optimize this Bi Map creation?

Comment: What exactly are you intending here?  It's not clear why you are using BiMap.  Are you trying to look it up based on the `Map<Item, Boolean>`?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think that [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for it.

Comment: (Are you looking for `Table`, rather than `BiMap`?  `Table` is a map with two keys, `BiMap` is a map in both directions.)